# Parameterizing format specifier in printf

Tags: c, format, printf

I have a few lines of output like the following:

```
    printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s \n", "Identity", "Identity", "float", "double", "long double");
    printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s \n", "Number", "LHS", "error", "error", "error");
```

As you can see, if I wanted to change the spacing between them, I would have to change the number 20 ten times. Is there a way to parameterize the format specifier? So that changing only once would change them all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can make the *field width* an asterisk (`*`), and supply the value as an `int` argument. Something like

```
printf("%-*s \n", width, "Identity");
```

where `width` is of type `int` holding the field width value. You can change the value of `width` to change the field width.

To quote the `C11` standard regarding this, chapter §7.21.6.1, *`fprintf()`*,

> An optional **minimum** *field width*. [...] The field width
>   takes the form of an asterisk `*` (described later) or a nonnegative decimal integer.

and related,

> As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
>   this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision.[...]